# Where did the r value go for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-biology

Question:
[image: question]
Answer:
[image: answer]

So I got the same answer except mine has e^rt instead of e^t so can someone explain why the r just disappeared and if my answer is still correct?

Comment: It's a typo. It should be $\exp(rt)$.

Comment: ok thank you so much I was thinking it was something weird cause of the initial condition